Draw the nilpotent cone of $sl_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$
The nilpotent cone of $sl_2(\mathbb{C})$ is the set of matrices $\{A=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&-a
\end{pmatrix}\ |\ a^2+bc=0\}$.
Then I was told that we can draw this nilpotent cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a real cone. I think this is because $a^2+bc=0$, but the formula of a cone is $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$, so how can we change $a^2+bc=0$ to the later one?

the "change of coordinates" $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y+z,y-z)$ is what you are looking for...
